# Final permutation table example with DES

Tags: encryption, des

This question [has been asked by another already](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100796/how-to-look-up-permutation-tables-in-des) but I can't comment on that.

There is a question in a book:

> Find the output of initial permutation box when input given in hexadecimal as:

$\texttt{0x0002 0000 0000 0001}$

How does this input have two `1s` at bits 15 and 64?

How do I look into the initial permutation table for the output:

$\texttt{0x0000 0080 0000 0002}$

Please also give any reference material.

Comment: @schroeder Ok,I ask simply how 2nd byte-02 get into '80' and last byte to 02? Actually my Q is similarly asked by another one though i am unable to understand.

Comment: Head over to the Crypto exchange for in-depth crypto.

Comment: @JoshuaFaust So should I post this in Cryptoexchange?

Comment: @schroeder Yes, you certainly should. I have no doubt that many of us could answer this for you but the most appropriate place for this questions is the Crypto Exchange.

Comment: According to your link, the input is actually $\texttt{0x 0000 0080 0000 0002}$, not $\texttt{0x 0002 0000 0000 0001}$, which is the answer (and what you have as input). Is this what you intended? I answered the question as asked.

Comment: @galvatron Sure it is correct but how you get 80 and 02 output for given Input? If you can provide some materials for basics it will help.

Comment: Wait, now I'm reading the link in the answer again. It says "final permutation" and so its result is incorrect as that is NOT the result of the final permutation. What I have is the result immediately after the initial permutation.

Comment: Okay, so your answer $\texttt{0x0000 0080 0000 0002}$ is actually the output of the final permutation, not the initial one. Could you update the question to reflect this? I updated my answer to show you where the bytes come from.

Comment: @galvatron From your answers far I am little more confused now.You have answered what I wanted appreciated that but, In this I dont get for which question your answer relates to,is it my question or my linked question?

Comment: @galvatron I request you to answer on my question that is not related to link.Thanks for your Answers though really.

Comment: @galvatron If you have book CNS by fourozan and mukhopadhay,my question is cleary mentioned in example( 6.1) , but may be book is wrong.Thanks , now I am satisfied with your explaination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference for DES is [FIPS 46-3](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips46-3/fips46-3.pdf). See page 10 for the permutations.

Write $\texttt{0x0002 0000 0000 0001}$ in binary. Start with $\texttt{0x0002}$:

```
0: 0000 (bits 1-4)
0: 0000 (bits 5-8)
0: 0000 (bits 9-12)
2: 0010 <--bit 15 is 1 (bits 13-16)
```

Bits 17-48 are all `0`. Now look at $\texttt{0x0001}$:

```
0: 0000 (bits 49-52)
0: 0000 (bits 53-56)
0: 0000 (bits 57-60)
1: 0001 <--bit 64 is 1 (bits 61-64)
```

Thus, bits 15 and 64 are set.

[At this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DES_supplementary_material), you can see the initial permutation and final permutation. It looks like the answer you're referring to is actually talking about the final permutation, so to match what you have, I'll be using that. Looking at the final permutation, the number "63" is the 15th bit, and the number "25" is the 64th bit. So your result is, in binary,

$\texttt{0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000}$ (bits 1-32, bit 25 set)
$\texttt{0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010}$ (bits 33-64, bit 63 set)

Or, in hexadecimal,

$\texttt{0x0000 0080 0000 0002}$.

This is the *final permutation*, not the initial one.